# Blank favicon for redirecting bookmark on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, facebook, favicon, facebook-chat

I've bookmarked the [Messenger website](https://www.messenger.com) on chrome. When visiting this website, users are redirected to their most recent conversation. As a result, my bookmark's favicon is left blank. Is there a way to add a favicon without hard linking to a specific conversation?

**EDIT**: I've solved my specific case with Messenger by signing out and signing in. A generic solution is yet to be seen.

Comment: I googled this problem and it happened to be about Messenger for me too

Answer (score 0):

As Joel already wrote, signing out from **Chrome browser** and in again solved it for me.